# Validating length depending on a setting in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Note that I am using CakePHP 1.3.

I would like to validate the length of several fields of a model depending on a limit defined by the administrator in the database.

I have one model called Setting through which I can fetch the maxLength values. My idea is to use the beforeValidate method to fetch them, and then set the $validate parameter accordingly :

```
<?php
class Mod extends AppModel
{   
    var $belongsTo = array('IBelong');
    var $hasMany = array('IHaz');

    function beforeValidate() {
        // Fetch the maxLength settings : requestAction to the SettingsController ?
        // Somehow do $this->Setting->find... ?

        // Then set the $validate attribute
    }
}
?>
```

What method can I use to get the maxLength values in the beforeValidate callback ?

Thanks !

Edit : following comments by Dave, here is what I am currently doing (and it works) :

```
<?php
class Mod extends AppModel
{   
    var $belongsTo = array('IBelong');
    var $hasMany = array('IHaz');

    function beforeValidate() {
        App::import('Model', 'Setting');
        $setting = new Setting();
        // Use $setting->find... to fetch the settings
        // Set the $validate attribute to validate using the settings
    }
}
?>
```

However, I am still not sure if this is the right approach.

Note that I have several attributes to validate, and I would like to avoid having to call $setting->find several times for best performance.

Answer (score 2):

Data Validation is very thoroughly explained in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html).

If you read the [Custom Validation Rules area](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules), you'll see an example of them pulling data from the database to use in their validation - exactly like what you want.

(Here's [Custom Validation Rules for 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#custom-validation-rules))

Comment: I saw this example indeed, but I wondered a) will this call the function for every field when I try to save the model ? I would like to avoid making 5 SQL queries, which is why I wanted to use beforeValidate. b) how can I call the find method of the Setting model from this callback ?

Comment: Why not just do what you wrote in your code - $this->Setting->find()  Nothing wrong w/ that assuming Setting is associated with Mod.  Then set your settings into $this->data['Setting'][] or something.

Comment: But what if Setting is not associated with Mod ? My Setting model is used to store generic settings for the application, so there is no real semantic link between Setting and Mod (using belongsTo or hasMany would not make sense)

Comment: @personne3000:  loadModel()

Comment: I did somewhat know about all this, but since I am not experienced in cakePHP I did not really know how to put all the pieces together. I should be able to make it work with loadModel, thank you

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if that's right - I don't think you can loadModel() from another model.

Comment: Indeed, after testing this, it seems loadModel is a method of Controller and not Model, so I can't use it from a model. Looks like I am still stuck here !

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by using App::import('Model', 'Setting'); $setting = new Setting();
However, I am not sure this is the right way to go !